# Writing "hahaha" versus describing the laugh

Tags: dialogue, description

When posting an excerpt of my book on a critiquing site, someone commented on my use of "hahaha" inside the dialogue instead of just having a laughing verb after or before it. They said it took them out of the reading. Obviously, this is subjective, so rather I will ask this:

Which alternative is the most popular and professional? Which do you see the most in writing?

The answers to this question said to use speech tags. But I thought this was bad, and within the phenomenon called *filtering*. In [another question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/34417/how-to-avoid-using-he-she-it-repetitively-in-action), a user taught me about this, and I've tried to take it to heart.

I thought the alternative was a separate line under, like this.

> -That's so funny!
>
> A thundering laugh rolled out of him.

Instead of:

> -That's so funny, Mick laughed.

The latter having *filtering*, in the way there's a "Mick laughed" in between the dialogue and the rest of the text.

So, I thought the alternatives were "hahaha" and having this separate line under. The problem is, which someone once told me, having specification for the dialogue at **a later time** isn't good, because it often makes the reader have to go back. The person said this in relation to not including name tags after the dialogue, but I believe it applies to the **way** dialogue is uttered, as in if it is laughed or said normally.

Comment: well, did the character laugh or literally say "ha ha ha"?

Comment: Maybe "hahaha" could be a cite? like, 'and he laughed "hahaha" when he said that.. ridiculous.' (or something on those lines), or if the laugh is emphasized, like really big; you could "say" that; "hahaha!!" (or something)

Answer (score 33):

## Dialogue quotes are for things a character actually says.

If your character says "hahaha" then fine.  But I've never heard anyone do that.  You might get a single "ha!" but that's an exclamation not a laugh.  Or someone might say "ha ha" (or even "ha ha ha") sarcastically.  Again, not a laugh.

If you want to tell your readers that your character laughed then, yeah, you need to just say so.  If the laughing comes *during* the dialogue, you can use a laughing tag.  Stylistically, many people recommend against using tags that aren't your basic "said" or "asked" but you can get away with a few.

> "It's...I can't even explain it," Griselda laughed.

Or you can describe the action directly.

> Griselda laughed.  "That's...just wow."

Using the phrase "hahaha" to indicate that someone is laughing is perfectly legitimate in texts, emails, and other informal settings.  Don't use it in your writing.

Comment: "Stylistically, many people recommend against using tags that aren't your basic 'said' or 'asked' but you can get away with a few." Really? I've always heard the opposite, that "'said' is too boring, use other words whenever possible, like exclaimed, announced, complained, shouted, explained, etc."

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Do you remember where you've heard that?  I've never seen that advice from professionals or writing teachers.  The idea is that boring is good; your brain just slides right by it.  The other words stand out and distract you from the dialogue.

Comment: It was from a middle school English teacher. Her arguments was the opposite, that boring is bad and we needed lots of variety. I see where both arguments come from.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Some people do agree with her, but they're in the minority.  The professional sources are against it.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms  I have learned the same thing, that there should be a variation in what speech verbs one uses afterwards. I've also heard that using speech tags should be avoided as in a whole.

Comment: *Don't use it in your writing.* Unless you're Terry Pratchett and you're making a point about maniacal laughter. Ahahahah!!!! **Ahahahahahahah!!!!!**

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms There's a difference in aims between middle school writing class and professional writing. Your teacher wants you to flex your vocab and find interesting ways to say something as a teaching exercise, rather than taking the 'easy' way out (for a middle-school student) and just using 'said' every sentence. Professionally, though, it's all about deciding where you want to place emphasis. What about this sentence should the reader be paying particular attention to? What's special about the event? Highlight those things with "interesting" words to contrast the "mundane" ones.

Comment: I know what you mean, but to me, my writings are "texts". A SMS message is something else. (As an aside, e-mail can be quite formal as well. That depends entirely on the context of the communications. If I'm in the process of applying for a job, you can bet those e-mails are going to look very different from one that's basically just a reminder to a friend to buy a food item for when they're coming over.)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms (cont.) So if the character has just said something in a non-remarkable way, just say 'said' - leaving the focus on *what* was said rather than *how* it was said ("That's interesting... here, look, the body's still warm," said Cotson) . If, however, *how* it was said should be taken note of ("Preposterous!" spluttered the general), then highlight it.

Comment: If you're reporting for news, boring is good, as you generally want to focus on what people said rather than how they said it, to want to report factually, so keep it simple unless otherwise necessary. If you're writing fiction, you'd want to take advantage of richer tags because those tags carries different subtleties to the story and how the characters are perceived in the dialogue. `"Sorry for the bruise", snarked Jack`, `"Sorry for the bruise", sobbed Jack`, `"Sorry for the bruise", sighed Jack` all have the exact same wording in the dialog, but they characterize Jack very differently.

Comment: @Kai True, I guess that does make sense.

Answer (score 9):

+1 to Cyn, much my answer; use a tag. I can add, I use a single "Ha!" a handful of times in a book. You can also describe the laugh in more detail; *Griselda laughed, and covered her mouth as she did for a few seconds. "Oh my god!"* I would increase the visual of that, there must be twenty kinds of laughing.

To me this goes for all verbal sound effects; I find it off-putting in novels when an author tries to simulate the sound of screams, moaning (in pleasure or pain), singing, grunting, or inarticulate anger.

Use tags, or just say "Mike grunted." Or describe them, use a metaphor, or an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

You want to immerse your reader in the story hence writing "hahaha" does not give a vivid definition of how the character felt whilst laughing.People read stories to get lost in the moment and feel like they are actually there ,so its the job of the writer to make it so.

*micheal burst out in fits of laughter clutching onto the chair for support.
"That..was..so..funny " he said between laughs. *

this gives the reader a vivid picture of the story as compared to a simple "hahaha"(which can also be interpreted as sarcasm).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in using *hahaha* as long as it's surrounded with a quote. I mean, I believe a character's style of laughter can be represented by a quoted word like "hahaha" or even "buhahaha". The key pointer here is to surround it by quotes so that the reader knows what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 'she laughed' is filtering, and I can't imagine a situation in which it would be. If you read widely you'll see that tagging with 'she laughed' is occasionally fine. It's when too many book-isms stray into the tags that it's annoying.  But, having said that it's not a filter, it's still hard for me to imagine someone speaking in a laugh. I'd use the laughter as an action tag, not a dialog tag. This is the difference between:

*"I can't believe you just said that," she laughed.*

and

*She laughed. "I can't believe you just said that.*

(very trivial difference, but I'd opt for the second.)

Filtering is when there's an extra (usually two-word) snippet between the viewpoint character and the experience.

***She saw*** her captor approach.

vs.

*Her captor approached.*

Other filter words and explanation can be found [here](https://annerallen.com/2017/06/filter-words-and-phrases-to-avoid-in-writing/). i don't think laughter is one of the filters, since it is not an action that leads to an experience, if that makes sense. Laughter *is* the experience.